# Android studio starts but doesn't install anything

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, windows-7-x64

I've downloaded and unzipped android-studio-ide-135.1538390-windows.zip, I already had a %JAVA_HOME% path and when I open studio.bat I get the application opened...

But not installed. I'm currently browsing a project, so the IDE is working, but as I didn't use any wizard, I don't get this:

> The individual tools and other SDK packages are saved outside the
>   Android Studio application directory. If you need to access the tools
>   directly, use a terminal to navigate to the location where they are
>   installed. For example:
>
> \Users\\sdk\

I also tried opening directly the studio.exe and the studio64.exe files. The latter acts just like the .bat, whereas studio.exe prompts a "no JVM installation foud. Please install a 32-bit JDK"

Since I have:

```
\android-studio\bin>echo %JAVA_HOME%
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13
>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_13
```

I supposed that this was just for 32 bit windows, and I am on a x64.

May I just work without installing anything? The first issue I have faced is that I cannot run an emulator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio no installation wizard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700800/android-studio-no-installation-wizard)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that link

Comment: I just realized that my question was `asked 2 days ago` whereas [Android Studio no installation wizard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700800/android-studio-no-installation-wizard) was `asked yesterday` :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SDK is apparently no longer bundled with Android Studio. You need to install it separately and then add the path to Android Studio in Configure->Project Defaults->Project Structure.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Just Check if you have this error?

You are also using a version of Java that isn't compatible with Android. You'll need to use Java 6 or 7 instead.
As `JDK_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` both are different

You need to install Java 7 as 8 is not supported on Android

- The latest Java 7 release can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).
- You may also need change the name of the environment variable `JDK_HOME` to `JAVA_HOME`.
  [Here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Setting+the+JAVA_HOME+Variable+in+Windows) is the blog post which explains how to do thta.

Hope it Helps!

Comment: Thanks, I have this error, but since I wanted a 64-bits installation I didn't think it was the problem. I have setted `JAVA_HOME`but not `JDK_HOME`, Where that should point to?. I have Java 7 (jdk1.7.0_13) so it's not the *latest* Java 7. May that be the problem?