# Android Studio no installation wizard

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have downloaded the latest Android Studio and when I run studio64.exe it opens Android Studio as a standalone application, however I would like to install it to my system.

The website says there is an installation wizard however I get taken straight to the Android Studio start screen. Is there still a way to install it on a Windows machine?

Comment: Did you download the file from official link? Why not launch "install.exe" instead?

Comment: Yes, it's from the official link, and there is no install.exe

Comment: If you download from official link the name will be like
Android-studio-bundle-(version number).exe
try this [Official Link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) i have downloaded it yesterday.

Comment: That link is for the SDK, not for Android Studio. I have downloaded Android Studio and it has been confirmed by a few other people that Android Studio no longer has an installer - see my answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out that Android Studio is now portable - like Eclipse. In other words, there is no installing, you just get the zip file, which contains everything you need, such as the executables that run Android Studio. You'll need to store this folder somewhere relevant and create a shortcut to the studio(64).exe file to run it from desktop/start menu.

The SDK is also no longer bundled with Android Studio, so that will need to be downloaded separately.

As of this post the Android Studio installation instructions by Google are out of date.

Comment: I have lost half an hour to figure out there is something wrong and find this answer. Any chance to get Google change few lines about this crucial change on their major android studio home page?

Comment: Thanks for that,4 hours later...How do we get the sdk now? I can't find it without having to get eclipse?

Comment: @vanzlyv you'll have to download the SDK separately using the SDK manager I assume. I haven't gotten around to doing it yet.

Comment: So do they not care about placing files properly around my operating system?  Now I have to try to figure out an appropriate location?  Garbage IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

you can get the sdk manager as stand alone installer.once installed you need to run it as "administrator", than only it will be able to download and install packages and api's. follow the given below link:

http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r23.0.2-windows.exe

Answer (score 0):

Check if its in compatible mode with your OS version of your machine. Right click on the downloaded bundle > Move to properties> Compatibility tab> Select Compatibility tab> Tick the check-box- Run in Compatibility mode> Select your OS version from the drop down.

You will get the set up wizard :)

Worked for me :)