# Portable Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to install android studio on my portable usb hard drive to run andoid studio in my school without install. Its is possible? Or maybe exist a portable version of android studio ? Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700800/android-studio-no-installation-wizard

Comment: I don't think it's too broad. It's very specific, whether it's possible to have portable android studio. Good question and good answers. I would expect it's something that many people want to know. I came upon this question when I searched "install android sdk portable". So the question may be "closed" according to SO but not as a reference that's easily found.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**AS (Android Studio)** itself is portable, however the **JDK (Java Development Kit)** which is required to run AS, is not. So you still need to install JDK on each computer you use.

You can download the AS versions here:
http://tools.android.com/download/studio/stable

**EDIT:**
You need to save the AS together with **SDK** files: 
http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

and if you have problems with **gradle**, it can be downloaded here:
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

To set up gradle for offline, go to:
<kbd>File</kbd> > <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Build, Execution, Deployment</kbd> > <kbd>Gradle</kbd> then check <kbd>Offline Work</kbd>. You will need to assign the service directory path (the path where gradle lives) or just paste the downloaded gradle zip into default directory, which is `C:/Users/<CurrentUser>/.gradle`.

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm running Linux Mint

Comment: When it comes to 100% offline usage AS is not portable by any means.

Answer (score 14):

It is not that easy as [FrozenFire](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35376806/342621) has told you. You need to add a number of entries into Android Studio's main configuration file to tell it to use and store other configuration files and logs relative to its executable. You also need to set a number of environment variables pointing to SDK, AVD, and Gradle's configuration directories.

I have created a number of [PowerShell scripts](https://github.com/toksaitov/AndroidStudioPortable.git) to download, extract, and prepare a portable environment for Android development (with Android SDK and Oracle JDK). You can either use them or take a look on how to create the environment on your own. Inside the repo you can also find a branch for Android Studio preview builds. You can also set the `AndroidStudioPortable-Definitions.ps1` script to download a specific version of Android Studio/SDK, or JDK. The scripts were tested on everything after Windows 7 including the Windows 7 itself.

Comment: Is there anyway to make Android Studio portable for Offline work? Even though if you move the gradle offline folder to your disc, it asks for Android build tools gradle and that there's no cashed file for this version.