# Transfer Android SDK from One PC to Another

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, sdk

If I have android studio on one pc, can I still use it on a different computer without having to download and set up android SDK again on the other system?

**EDIT:**
I simply transferred the android SDK folder to the other laptop, uninstalled android studio from the new one, then installed it all over again

Comment: In that case use a remote desktop :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to run Android Studio or any other program on another machine without installing it, it must be a portable program. Honestly I haven't tried it before but I found a couple of resources that suggests that indeed it is possible to do that. [Link](https://portapps.io/app/android-studio-portable/) and [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34149226/portable-android-studio)